# Mapping from Unicode character to LaTeX-Symbol for BibTeX?

Tags: bibtex, unicode

I'm writing a little BibTeX exporter for the publication database of my institute. We do have a lot of authors with all kind of weird characters in their names, which get the "WTF is Unicode?"-treatment from BibTeX.

As I have to preprocess author names and titles before exporting anyway, I thought that I could replace as much unicode characters as possible with their LaTeX equivalent. There's an image with such a mapping on [bibtex.org](http://www.bibtex.org/SpecialSymbols/):
[image: mapping]

But that image is

1. incomplete (e.g. capital German umlauts are missing) and
2. not of much use to me in this form.

Does someone know of such a mapping that is as complete as possible and available in a machine-readable format?

**Edit**: Juan's XML is probably as complete as it gets (I'll post a Python dictionary reduced to unicode and LaTeX on github). But in the meantime, I also found the mapping that [Zotero](https://www.zotero.org/) uses. It can be found in their [SVN-Repository](https://www.zotero.org/svn/extension/branches/2.0/translators/BibTeX.js).

**Edit2**: OK, the Python dictionary can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/beniwohli/798549), and the XSL Style Sheet to convert Juan's XML into a Python dictionary is [here](https://gist.github.com/beniwohli/798546).

Comment: Use biber+biblatex or bibtex8?

Comment: we don't use the exported bibtex files ourselves. It's a service for people that download papers from our website. I can't influence how they use the bibtex files we provide.

Comment: Good question!  There are other circumstances where this mapping could be valuable.

Comment: Many citation exporters don't try to create BibTeX-compatible databases any more, and I think that's pretty ok since BibTeX is completely outdated. I think you don't have to put much effort in supporting a decade-old, broken system.

Comment: Philipp: What alternatives are there that are widely in use? I'm a programmer, not a researcher, so I'm not current on this topic :)

Comment: piquadrat: The mapping you linked to is great, but how did you actually apply it? It would be great to use this mapping to update this ancient [Python unicode-to-LaTeX recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/252124-latex-codec/).

Comment: These links seem to have broken.

Comment: @TextGeek I updated the links. It probably broke because, by coincidence, somebody signed up on github with the username matching one of the gist IDs, at which point GitHub displays the user profile instead of the gist

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [a related question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354067/map-between-latex-commands-and-unicode-points), there is

> ... [an XML file](http://www.w3.org/Math/characters/unicode.xml) from the W3C. It maps Unicode to HTML, MathML, LaTeX, Mathematica, and others. (The file is 1.4 MB, uncompressed.)
>
> You can read more about it here: http://www.w3.org/TR/unicode-xml/

Comment: Here's a web app based on the data from that XML file. Enter Unicode and loop up LaTeX and vice versa. http://www.johndcook.com/unicode_latex.html

Comment: Also see https://digitalheir.github.io/mathy-unicode-characters/ - based on that same XML file

Answer (score 10):

You can use `biber` with the optional arguments for the bibdata `bibtex` and the exported bib encoding (`UTF8`).

```
biber --bblencoding=UTF-8 --bibencoding=latin1 --allentries --bibdata <file.bib>
```

Comment: this command does not seem to work anymore. `allentries` and `bibdata` are `unknown option`s on biber v2.11

Comment: It worked for me on the contrary of `bibtex %` which wouldn't accept accents.

Comment: Current version of `biber` can convert UTF-8 `bib` file to ASCII using the following command: `biber --tool  --output-encoding=ascii -O output-file.bib input-file.bib`