# Naming convention for papers, articles and bibliographic references

Tags: bibtex, naming

This is not strictly speaking a TeX question, but I think every TeX author will have been confronted by it at some point.

What convention do you follow when naming PDF copies of articles downloaded from the web?

I used to follow the same naming convention I used for BiBTeX entries, i.e. *main author:year:title initials*. For example, the "Go To Statement Considered Harmful" by Dijkstra (1968) would be saved as `dijkstra:68:gtsch.pdf`.

Now I'm not so happy about this convention because the colon, which was fine while I was working under Windows, is a reserved character under UNIX.

Corollary question: what convention do you follow for BiBTeX entries?

Comment: I would not recommend using colons in a file name. On some OSes, it can make things harder, especially if you need to script stuff with these files.

Comment: Nevertheless, the colon is *not* a reserved character in UNIX.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Author, year in a Harvard-like manner, i.e. `Djikstra68.pdf`. Multiple papers from the same author and year have letters appended (`Djikstra68a.pdf`, `Djikstra68b.pdf`). This has limitations, but is enough assuming you have one `.bib` file per (major) project.

BibTeX reference keys are the same as the corresponding PDF file, without file extension.

Comment: This is also similar to the automatic naming scheme of [Jabref](http://jabref.sourceforge.net/). It uses the full year, though.

Comment: I don't like the `a,b,...` distiction for articles in the same year, since it may often happen that an aricle `Surname12b.pdf` gets `[Sur12a]` biblabel when only `Surname12b.pdf` and `Surname12c.pdf` are cited in a document.

Comment: @tohecz The internal reference used by (La) TeX and BibTeX or Biber is not related to how the citation appears in the document...

Comment: @PaulGaborit I cannot help myself, but you must consider me begin stupid.

Answer (score 4):

In my group we use author-year-venue/journal, that is, `dijkstra-68-cacm.pdf` or `liedtke-95-sosp.pdf`. As You, we append letters if there is more than one paper from the same author and year in the same venue; however, that is very unlikely to happen.

I personally find the encoding of the venue into the name very helpful to recall the entry during writing (more helpful than a keyword or an encoded title). In CS, where the top conferences have displaced journals as the premier publication channel, papers are colloquially often mentioned by venue and year: *You know the stuff John has presented in their OOPSLA '06 paper, do you?*

Answer (score 3):

Our university group has strict rules for paper names in the repository.
I'm using them for much more than only papers, because I am used to this naming convention.

YEARautour-paper-name.pdf

An example:
[A Guide to Natural Naming by Daniel Keller from 1990](http://delivery.acm.org/10.1145/390000/382637/p95-keller.pdf?ip=141.54.159.146&acc=ACTIVE%20SERVICE&CFID=93747005&CFTOKEN=96649231&__acm__=1341452137_9c9a91d2bdf9521b1b0f7224323e7b3a) will be named

1990keller-a-guide-to-natural-naming.pdf

This will sort the PDF Files corresponding to year, name and content.

The bibtex key is made simpler by omitting the first two digits and stop words:

90keller-guide-natural-naming

Answer (score 0):

I can't remember what paper is what by knowing only author's name and year. I use

> Abate, Bracci, Sua, Tovena 2010, Localization of Atiyah classes.pdf

The spaces in the name are never a problem, because I never process these files through any software. Spaces are a pain for .tex files because you want to apply tex to them.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a bit of noise here, I add a `where` field to my bibliographies, where I record the URL where I found the document. The documents themselves I store just under the original name (as long as it isn't the very original `book.pdf`).

**Edit:** If you use something like Zotero (a tool to organize bibliographies) it saves the webpage as 'url' field and even adds a 'urldate' (the time you visited the webpage). (But still, Zotero is not perfect.)

Comment: +1 for recommending zotero, you may wan to have a look at my answer [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18848/workflow-for-managing-references/114973#114973) for workflow that invests in Zotero + `biblatex`+`biber`+ text editor that supports `biber` backend (I use TexStduio).