# Are there tools for importing patents from patent databases into BibTeX?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I need to import a large number of patents (e.g., all the patents by a particular inventor or assigned to a specific assignee) into BibTeX format. Are there tools for doing this?

I'm not interested in single patents or in approaches that do this one patent at a time, but in ways to import large batches all at once. In particular, I'd be interested in tools provided directly by online patent databases  and repositories (e.g. the [USPTO](http://patft.uspto.gov/netahtml/PTO/search-bool.html) or the [EPO](https://register.epo.org/espacenet/regviewer?)).

Comment: Sounds like a challenging project! Are the patents registered in multiple countries or in one country only?

Comment: @Mico: I'd be satisfied if I could just get batches (e.g. from a search result for inventor or assignee) of the USPTO.

Comment: Have you considered using JabRef? It lets you create custom import filters that take csv files as their input(s) and produce bib files. Check it out at http://jabref.sourceforge.net/help/CustomImports.php.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius What format will the output from this services be? CSVs? Web-pages?

Comment: @Sveinung: [Web pages](http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO2&Sect2=HITOFF&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsearch-adv.htm&r=0&p=1&f=S&l=50&Query=IN%2FWilliam+AND+IN%2FGates+AND+IN%2F%22William+H.%22&d=PTXT).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Zotero**
[Zotero](http://www.zotero.org/) is the answer. I made a search for [*Borregaard*](http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO2&Sect2=HITOFF&p=1&u=/netahtml/PTO/search-bool.html&r=0&f=S&l=50&TERM1=Borregaard&FIELD1=&co1=AND&TERM2=&FIELD2=&d=PTXT) at the USPTO and got a long list of hits. In Firefox, I got that little yellow letterbox (the *rightmost* of the four small icons to the right in the address bar). I clicked that icon, and got a pop up list of all the hits. I selected some, and clicked OK, and *Viola!* ; all the patents were imported to Zotero. From there, it is just to export all to `bibtex`-format.

If you are not familiar with Firefox or Zotero, it is very easy. Zotero also works with Portable Firefox, see [`PortableApps.com`](http://portableapps.com/)(I use it). And you can use `Zotero standalone` if you are using Safari or Chrome. I assume it works the same way, but I have only tested Window$ 7, Firefox Portable 11 and Zotero 3.03.

**Mendeley**
I also assume that you can do the same trick with [Mendeley](http://www.mendeley.com/), but I have not tested.

Comment: +1 For Zotero and is also available for Chrome or Safari aficionados.

Comment: Wow!! That's incredible.

Comment: Incredible, for sure. And remember if you have trouble with the import and need to fine tune the site translators (the import filters), there are very helpful and responsive people at the Zotero Forum. F.ex visit the _Site translator_ -forum at http://forums.zotero.org/6/ .

Comment: @Sveinung, +1 for zotero, you may want to have a look at workflow that makes use of `biblatex` package, `biber` backend, and a text editor that supports `biber`(I use TexStudio) [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18848/workflow-for-managing-references/114973#114973).

Comment: Zotero seems to be having problems with google patents (in their forums they say the problems are solved, I would beg to differ). The USPTO site works nicely.

Comment: @craq My answer is no longer up to date, because Firefox has changed its architecture. You have to use the Zotero stand alone with Firefox.

Comment: @Sveinung yes you're right. I was using the stand alone program, but it still struggled with some google patents. (I later discovered that it works OK with most google patents, but not the first one I tried. I should also say that even when it worked, zotero was able to pull much more info off USPTO than off google.)