# Best way to do referencing with LaTeX? - I use Zotero to manage citations

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, biber

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25701/bibtex-vs-biber-and-biblatex-vs-natbib)

**What's the best way to add references and a bibliography to a LaTeX document?**

Note: I'm using [Zotero](http://www.zotero.org/) as my citation manager, which has an export to [bibtex](http://www.bibtex.org/) feature.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are after here. Do you mean for example how to get the appropriate `\cite` statements into your source, which packages to load for a particular type of bibliography, where to find bibliography style, ...? We need more detail I think.

Comment: Have a look at [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/4012), it might answer your question. Essentially, it really depends or your needs, what kind and style of references you need.

Comment: @AT   I use `Zotero` also, for automation of bibliography process, you may want to have a look at my answer [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18848/workflow-for-managing-references/114973#114973).