# got a problem using BibTex in a 64bit PC

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex

To insert Bibliography using BibTex, I exported my references from Zotero using the .bib extension and saved it in the folder BibTex/bib (specifically C:\swp55\TCITeX\BibTeX\bib\mybib) and chose a style C:\swp55\TCITeX\BibTeX\bst. I then inserted citation and bibliography, but I only got "?" as citation and nothing for bibliography. Please suggest me what to do, I have little if any technical background. 
If important my pc is 64bit.

Comment: if you change the bibliographystyle to plain instead of C:\swp55\TCITeX\BibTeX\bst does it work then? but like @Canaaerus says, a MWE would be very helpfull

Comment: @Daniel, you may have a look at [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18848/workflow-for-managing-references/114973#114973) workflow investing in Zotero + `biblatex`+`biber`. Let me know if that was useful.

Comment: @doctorate that helpful. It is working now. I didn't know that I had to compile the document again. There was some minor problem too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `bib` file should lie in the same directory as your `tex` file. Also make sure to run `latex`, then `bibtex` and then `latex` again another *2 times*.
Furthermore look at the output of those commands for any error messages. A `blg` file should contain an even more detailed log of the `bibtex` run.

If that does not help, you should post a MWE containing `tex` and `bib` file, as well as the exact commands you use for compiling everything.

Comment: It does not have to lie in the same directory, that just makes the linking really easy.

Comment: @Rick: Of course you are right. That's why I said _“should lie”_ as this is about getting a basic setup working.

Comment: @RickdeGroot and @canaaerus;
I am using SWP( I don't know much about latex. I just followed the steps to insert bibliography and citation, but it couldn't work for me.

Comment: I have no experience with SWP so I can't help you any further.