# BibTex: citing IEEE standard

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing

My downloaded citation looks like this:

```
@ARTICLE{893287, 
author={}, 
journal={IEEE Std. 1516-2000}, title={IEEE Standard for Modeling and Simulation (M Amp;S) High Level Architecture (HLA) - Framework and Rules}, 
year={2000}, 
month={ }, 
volume={}, 
number={}, 
pages={i -22}, 
keywords={Keywords: architecture, class attribute, federate, federation, federation execution, federation object model, framework, high level architecture, instance attribute, interaction class, joined federate, object class, object model template, rules, runtime infrastructure, simulation object model;}, 
doi={10.1109/IEEESTD.2000.92296}, 
ISSN={},}
```

After typesetting, it looks like this:

> [1] Ieee standard for modeling and simulation (m amp;s) high level archi- tecture (hla) - framework and rules. IEEE Std. 1516-2000, pages i --22, 2000.

But I was wondering whether it should look like this:

> [2] IEEE Std 1516-2000. IEEE Standard for Modeling and Simulation (M&S) High Level Architecture (HLA) - Framework and Rules. Technical report, IEEE.

The later one was found while I was reading someone else's bibliography, and I think it just looks better than mine (for example it has **M&S** instead of **m amp;s**). However I wasn't sure about this.

So which one is better, [1] or [2]? Is there a rule?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The difference comes from the protection of the data fields. If you wish to keep the original format you need to put one extra pair of braces around the capitalizations etc.

*IEEE Download Citation* mechanism spits out these odd BibTeX entries and it's certainly not acceptable as you have found out. So there is almost always some work to do after downloading from IEEE, e.g.,  journal names comes out as `journal={some journal, IEEE Transactions on}` and you have to revert it each time.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{filecontents*}{testing.bib}
@ARTICLE{893287, 
author={}, 
journal={IEEE Std. 1516-2000}, 
title={{IEEE Standard for Modeling and Simulation {(M\&S)} High Level Architecture {(HLA)} - Framework and Rules}}, 
year={2000}, 
volume={}, 
pages={i -22}, 
doi={10.1109/IEEESTD.2000.92296}, 
}
\end{filecontents*}

\title{IEEE article}
\author{Theman Dlegend}

\begin{document}\maketitle
\lipsum[1]See \cite{893287} for more info 
\bibliographystyle{ieeetran}
\bibliography{testing}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you saying your solution is to use the package filecontents?

Comment: @sphere No it's just there to make the example self contained.

Comment: Warning: this is not the right format for citing IEEE standards. The title should be unquoted italics and the number plain text. see [IEEE's citation reference](https://www.ieee.org/documents/ieeecitationref.pdf)

Comment: @BryanP It's the official `.bst` style. It doesn't matter what it does.

Comment: Can you please explain what is in the testing.bib?

Comment: @percusse, do you think it is right to have the comma before the closing quotes in `and Rules,"`?

Answer (score 6):

None of them is correct, the corrected format should be as follows (just an example, which is demonstrate in page 10 of  [How to Use the IEEEtran BIBTEX Style](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bibtex/IEEEtran_bst_HOWTO.pdf) ).

[image]

If you want to cite your reference within IEEE standard, you should do it as IEEE required. This is 
[How to Use the IEEEtran BIBTEX Style](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bibtex/IEEEtran_bst_HOWTO.pdf) and [the official BibTeX style](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bibtex/) .

Enjoy citing!

Comment: This should be the right (and accepted) answer as it respects IEEE's format.

Comment: @TeddyvanJerry It really shouldn't, since it's not even answering the correct question. The question was "how to cite an IEEE standard (i.e. a document published by IEEE)", while this answer answers "how to cite something following IEEE journals' citation format requirements". The IEEEtran bibtex style has nothing to do with the question, as the person asking never specified they were writing a document for one of IEEE's journals.

Answer (score 3):

My answer is not purely about LaTex. I would recommend you to use a tool such as [Zotero](http://www.zotero.org/). It is plug-in of Firefox, that manages your bibliography. You can extract all the bibliographic information of a source, at once, by a simple click, either from a pdf format, or a web-page. You can save your pdf's, organize your collection.

But for your case, I would recommend Zotero, because Zotero create a BibTex file for you, with elements you select. Zotero does the IEEE (Or any other) formatting for you, it is a simple option in the Options menu.

Comment: +1 for recommending `Zotero`, you may have a look at my answer [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18848/workflow-for-managing-references/114973#114973) for automated workflow making use of `biblatex`, `biber` backend program, and text editor that supports `biber`, I use TexStudio.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple answer perhaps. IEEE Standards doesn't look like its a journal therefore it should not be defined as such. If you define the title instead + publisher + url in @misc this would be a more appropriate reference.

Comment: It is advisable to show what you mean through code rather. Could you provide the community with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that highlights what you mean, since I'm not sure whether this answers the question exactly.