# how can I force natbib/unsrtnat to abbreviate first names in bibliography?

Tags: bibtex, natbib

my question is similar to this one:  [How to abbreviate author's firstname in bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98567/how-to-abbreviate-authors-firstname-in-bibliography)

...but I'm having trouble implementing the solution. I can't find my .bst file to change the format.name line. 
Here's what I'm using right now:

```
\usepackage[numbers, sort&compress]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
```

I use mendeley as a reference manager, if that matters. I liked abbrvnat until I noticed that it put my references out of order of appearance and into alphabetical order instead. What I need is something that pairs the abbreviation function of abbrvnat and the ordering by appearance function of unsrtnat.

I'm fairly new at this, any help is appreciated and apologies if this is a very basic question. Let me know if you need more information and thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example with bibliography ([MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Please be more specific about how the abbreviation process should be performed. E.g., should first-name initials come before or after the surname?

Comment: Hi @Mico , that doesn't really matter - I noticed that abbrvnat did F. Lastname and that would be fine, as long as it's consistent. The issue is that Mendeley sometimes has only partial information from the article (i.e. only a first initial) and sometimes full names, and what I get with unsrtnat is a mix of the two!