# No space between author's initials and surname

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, formatting

So writing my thesis with LaTeX but when rendering, there is no space between author initials and surname in the bibliography. So:

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEE}
```

and

```
@article{knight_idempotent_2003,
    title = {Idempotent {Vector} {Design} for {Standard} {Assembly} of {Biobricks}},
    url = {https://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/21168},
    language = {en},
    urldate = {2019-05-27},
    journal = {MIT Synthetic Biology Working Group},
    author = {Knight, Thomas},
    year = {2003},
}
```

produces

T.Knight, “Idempotent Vector Design for Standard Assembly of Biobricks,” MIT Synth. Biol. Work. Group, 2003.

With no space between the initial (T.) and the surname (Knight). I've been following [this post's answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98567/how-to-abbreviate-authors-firstname-in-bibliography) to make LaTeX abbreviate first names by editing the IEEE.bst file as it is instructed. Maybe something there is not allowing for the space between the author's initials and his/her last name?

This is my updated .bst file:

in **format.names:**

```
{ s nameptr "{f.~ }{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=
```

in **format.crossref.editor:**

```
{ editor #2 "{f. }{vv }{ll}{ jj}" format.name$ "others"
```

Comment: Why do you want a space? `IEEE` is one of the standard styles, and having no space is fine. There is a dot anyway.

Comment: @gernotsaysReinstateMonica: It seems the ieee style itself doesn't use initials, but rather the modifications in this style to use the first name initials. Anyway, typographically, I don't  think this is fine.

Comment: Would consider using `biblatex-ieee`?

Comment: What happens with `author = "Thomas Knight"`?

Comment: @gernotsaysReinstateMonica just because the Thesis Office wants it that way

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Nothing changed

Comment: @Bernard I can't use biblatex package because it collides with other packages of the university's thesis template's one.