# Sort .bib file from within TexShop

Tags: bibtex, sorting, texshop

Is there a way to sort a BibTeX file from within TexShop? For instance, I would like to have all items of type `@proceedings` at the end of the file, and the items otherwise sorted alphabetically (say by the name of the first author).

I'm not referring to sorting the references in a compiled document (using a `.bst` style), but rather the BibTeX entries themselves in a `.bib` source file.

I used to be able to do this on Windows using WinEdt. Can I achieve something similar in TexShop on Mac OS X?

Comment: You can probably do something with BibDesk or JabRef.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TeXShop is a simple editor for Mac Systems. You are looking for a frontend for managing `bib`-files. This can be done by other programs. Here a small list:

---

- [JabRef](http://jabref.sourceforge.net/) -- platform independent
- [BibDesk](http://bibdesk.sourceforge.net/) -- only Mac
- [citavi](http://www.citavi.com/) -- only Windows
- [zotero](http://www.zotero.org/) -- platform independent, web application
- [mendeley](http://www.mendeley.com/) -- platform independent

---

Comment: @Bogdan, +1 for recommending zotero, if TexShop supports `biber` you can invest in `biblatex` package, if not I recommend another text editor, e.g., TexStudio. You may have a look at a workflow to make use of Zotero+`bilatex`+`biber` [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18848/workflow-for-managing-references/114973#114973)

Comment: +1 for BibDesk -- its interop with emacs and AucTex is good, meaning I can pound away in emacs, making new references at high speed without mousing, import them every now and then into BibDesk for canonicalization and cleanup, and write them back out to disk for future emacs sessions.