# A follow-up question on managing bibliography workflow

Tags: biblatex, biber

I felt this should be a follow-up question. If not, please remove it. The original question was [Workflow for managing references?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18848/workflow-for-managing-references/115299#115299). I am using TeXStudio 2.5.2 in Windows 7, `biber` and `biblatex` for the bibliography. I have followed the excellent guide that @doctorate has provided, but I have found two minor flaws.

When I copy an article from Zotero directly to a `.tex` document, or when I export to a `.bib` file, the names of the authors are not correct. For example names like: Gregoire and Chate have an accent on the e's and while they should be imported in the bibliography like this:

```
Gr\'{e}goire and Chat\'{e}
```

They are in fact copied with the accents, so when I compile my document I get random symbols on these names. Is there a way to correct this, or use a different tool? For now, these occurrences are not many, so I manually corrected everything and it works beautifully! :)

The second part is that the field `urldate` actually imports a field: "Visited on XX/XX/XXXX" that was not there in the MWE. Again, I deleted the field in the `.bib` file and it works, I'm just wandering why it didn't show on that setup and it does in mine.

As I am finishing my first ever LaTeX document and I am new to Tex.SE this is probably a final question for the meta. Are we allowed to use code other users provide as examples?

Any suggestions are really welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue of names with accent letter (or other non ASCII character) can be solved using

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

For the issue about `urldate` you can suppress it from the output using

```
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{urlyear}}
```

For the meta question: the contribution to Tex.se are under cc-wiki attribution license, so they can be used.

Answer (score 4):

FWIW - while using utf-8 as per above is surely preferably where your bibtex implementation allows (as biber/bilatex do), you can get Zotero to escape accented characters in bibtex: 
In the Zotero Preferences, under "Export" make sure the box "Display Character Set on Export" is checked. Then, when exporting to Bibtex, select a non-utf-8 charset - typically ISO-8859 - and Zotero will escape accented letters and many (though not all) other utf-8 characters.