# BibTeX error "inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8: not set up for use with LaTeX"

Tags: bibtex, unicode

So I am trying to get BibTex to work and I run into the above error: . After a quick search in here I found that it is a problem with extra space in the BibTex file that could be solved by adding the `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00A0}{~}` to the preamble. So I did that but I still get the error. I have added the part of the preamble where I have added the line. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong? (Using Texmaker on mac)

```
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}         
\usepackage[english]{babel}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00A0}{~}
\usepackage{verbatim}            
\usepackage{shortvrb}            
\usepackage{courier}             
\usepackage{ae}                  
\usepackage{booktabs}            
\usepackage{color}               
\usepackage{enumerate}           
\usepackage{longtable}                  
\usepackage{palatino}               
\usepackage{footmisc}                       
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage[font={small}]{caption}
```

Comment: Rather than that long list of packages, you should show the problematic entry in the `.bib` file.

Comment: `bibtex` is inherently 7 bit.  See this [FAQ question](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=biblatex) for some discussion.  Either you need to use tex sequences such as `\"a` for accents in your bibliography, or your need to switch to an 8bit system.  `biblatex` would be my choice.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Please see [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9795/5763) for a possible answer: Use `biber` and `biblatex`.

Comment: Look around http://newton.ex.ac.uk/tex/pack/bibtex/btxdoc/btxdoc.html for a lot of BibTeX suggestions. Make sure there is no non-ASCII character in the *.bib files, use e.g. `{\"a}` for accents (that way BibTeX collates (almost) right).

Comment: Okay so I switched to BibLatex (so much metter so thanx for that), upgraded to TeXLive 2012, and made sure I had no strange letters, apostrophs, lines etc in the jabref - that solved it. Thanks for all the suggestions